# Scripting javascript in clojurescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, coffeescript, clojurescript

I'm looking for easier/ faster ways to build client side web apps and was told that I should look into Clojurescript.

Can you use Clojurescript to script javascript to run in a web browser? Is there some benefits to scripting in clojurescript than regular javascript?

What's the differences between Clojurescript and Typescript/ Coffeescript in relation to faster/ easier development?

Comment: In my opinion TypeScript won : https://medium.com/@basarat/typescript-won-a4e0dfde4b08#.8mzp5939q 

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Clojurescript is a functional language that (because of its immutable data structures) is well suited to working with Facebook's React. There are a variety of React-based frameworks/libraries to choose from, and an active community to help you.

One of the advantages is that you get 'live coding' - this means that all you need to do is save your code and it will be automatically compiled and running in your browser. See Figwheel for this.

Also your production code will be only be as large as it needs to be due to the use of Google Closure's Dead Code Elimination.